# Windows xp does't let me chose ubuntu using an USB

Tags: installation, 13.04, usb, windows, startup

I have downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 in a pen-drive, but when I restart the computer, it doesn't let mi choose.

Comment: How did you create the USB?

Comment: Doesn't let you choose how? where exactly? Are you installing Ubuntu from within Windows or what?

Comment: I am installing Ubuntu in windows form a pen drive that has Ubuntu, that I installed form the same computer with Universal Installer USB 1.9.3.6.

Comment: I'm a little confused, could anybody tell me how do I try it with out installing it???

Comment: You need to go to your BIOS and tell it to boot from USB as your primary option. You can't "boot" from USB when you are already inside Windows XP because you already booted XP.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to go to BIOS of your computer and change the boot order to read the USB before it reads the hard drive.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: And... where is BIOS?